# pod update will not update to latest version of pod no matter what I do

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have looked at the related Stack Overflow questions and tried the recommendations there to no avail as well as cocoapods's github issues.

I manage the TensorIOTensorFlow pod and recently released two updates to that pod, 1.15 and 1.15.1. Both releases were tagged on GitHub and pushed to trunk after linting using `pod trunk push TensorIOTensorFlow.podspec` from the project's root directory.

See https://github.com/doc-ai/tensorio-tensorflow-ios

It has now been more than twelve hours since I released the 1.15.1 update and no matter what I do I cannot get `pod update` to update a local project from the 1.15 version to the 1.15.1 version or `pod install` to install anything other than the 1.15 version.

I have tried clearing the cocoapods cache:

```
$ rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
$ rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
$ pod cache clean --all
```

I have tried updating my local spec repo:

```
$ pod install --repo-update
$ pod update --repo-update
$ pod repo update
```

I have tried both `pod update` and `pod install` after removing the project's Pods directory and Podfile.lock. I have tried both of these in an existing project and a new project and on a separate machine with a first time install of cocoapods.

I have tried targeting the version specifically in the pod file:

```
pod 'TensorIOTensorFlow', '1.15.1'
```

Only to get the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "TensorIOTensorFlow":
  In Podfile:
    TensorIOTensorFlow (= 1.15.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `TensorIOTensorFlow (= 1.15.1)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

In spite of that error, and particularly frustrating, trunk seems to be aware of the 1.15.1 version:

```
$ pod trunk info TensorIOTensorFlow

TensorIOTensorFlow
    - Versions:
      - 0.1.0 (2019-04-09 19:29:30 UTC)
      - 0.1.1 (2019-05-09 17:43:06 UTC)
      - 0.3.0 (2019-12-18 18:44:18 UTC)
      - 0.3.1 (2020-01-23 23:36:35 UTC)
      - 1.13.4 (2020-05-01 21:16:32 UTC)
      - 1.13.5 (2020-05-08 21:13:09 UTC)
      - 1.13.6 (2020-05-26 20:05:09 UTC)
      - 1.15 (2020-05-27 17:06:58 UTC)
      - 1.15.1 (2020-05-27 23:44:11 UTC)
```

But pod search does not see it:

```
$ pod search TensorIOTensorFlow

-> TensorIOTensorFlow (1.15)
   The TensorFlow (unofficial) build used by TensorIO for iOS.
   pod 'TensorIOTensorFlow', '~> 1.15'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/doc-ai/tensorio-tensorflow-ios
   - Source:   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorio-build/r1.15/TensorIO-TensorFlow-1.15_0.tar.gz
   - Versions: 1.15, 1.13.6, 1.13.5, 1.13.4, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.0 [trunk repo]
```

To be sure, this is *after* I deleted the 1.15 and 1.15.1 versions with `pod delete` and tried pushing them to trunk again. Before that, `pod search` **did** show the 1.15.1 version but I still couldn't get a project to upgrade to it.

Finally, I have tried uninstalling and re-installing cocoapods, and as I mentioned, I have also tried all of this on a new machine with a first time install of the latest version of cocoapods, and I still cannot get the 1.15.1 version of the pod.

Comment: You could try temporarily pinning to the commit `pod 'TensorIOTensorFlow', :git => 'https://github.com/doc-ai/tensorio-tensorflow-ios.git', :commit => ' 16f906b'`

Comment: @LouFranco Thank you, yes this does function as a workaround. I can also use :tag => '1.15.1' to target that particularly release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the CDN can be laggy. To workaround and directly load from the GitHub repo, add `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` to the Podfile.

Note that it will be much slower.

UPDATE: The root cause looks to be fixed now. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9826

Comment: Thank you @paul-beusterien, yes this does work. So is this really a wait-and-see issue? I've experienced some lag with cocoapods before but never longer than an hour, if that.

Comment: Yes - the CDN typically updates on the order of 10 minutes, so there might be something unusual going on today

Comment: Looks like the CDN has finally updated and after a `pod repo update` a `pod update` correctly grabs 1.15.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue I have opened:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9827

And, I have followed @paul-beusterien answer. And here is a sample

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'YourTarget' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for YourTarget
  pod 'YourPod', '10.3.0'
end
```

So I added

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

on the top of my Podfile

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `.podspec` points to last pod version, it probably needs an updated version.